# How to make an imageview slide like default call screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

[image]How can we make an imageview to slide like default call screen , like swipe left to reject call and swipe right to answer call ? I have no experience on animations on android , so where do i start ?

something like this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this library
https://github.com/nadavfima/GlowPadView

Otherwise you'll have to use SurfaceView and do the animations, touch events, etc... manually

Comment: here is the source code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/widget/SlidingTab.java